# Evento tecla enter no input

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web

Bom dia, eu tenho um `input` fora de um `form` e gostaria de quando alguém digitasse nele e apertasse a tecla enter alguma função rodasse, porem não sei como fazer..

```
<input type="text" value="texto" />
```

Comment: Relacionado: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803376/form-submit-on-keycode-enter-13

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```js
const inputEle = document.getElementById('enter');
inputEle.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (key == 13) { // codigo da tecla enter
    // colocas aqui a tua função a rodar
    alert('carregou enter o valor digitado foi: ' +this.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="enter" type="text" value="texto" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função jQuery [Keypress](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

```js
jQuery('#textbox').keypress(function(event){

 var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
 if(keycode == '13'){
  alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox');
 }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="textbox" type="text" value="texto" />
```